# Configuring a Heroku Rails app for CKEditor to work on Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ckeditor, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using [this gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) to integrate CKEditor into my Rails app, with paperclip to handle image uploading.

I no longer want Heroku to serve my CKEditor-uploaded images anymore, so I'm switching to Cloudfront and found [this tutorial](https://leanpub.com/cloudfront_rails/read).

As I understood (from the tutorial), I can use Cloudfront without using an S3 bucket, as Cloudfront will automatically fetch my precompiled static assets stored on Heroku. But I'm so confused:

1. Will image uploaded via CKEditor be included in the asset pipeline? So that when precompiled, will be served by Cloudfront?
2. The tutorial said I need to change all image links to <%= image_tag('...') %> so that it'll point to Cloudfront and work. But this is only possible when I hard-coded the image, not the case when a user uploaded one in his text and stored in the database. Am I wrong and how to solve it?
3. Will this method (not using S3 bucket) work for other "dynamic" images such as User's avatars, post's cover images, etc...?

I don't want to use S3 bucket as it will involve the use of asset_sync. Any help is appreciated, thanks!